# Retrieve `valueForKey` as string

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a `NSArray` that contain three keys with their corresponding values… When I retrieve the value for a key with the method `valueForKey:` I get this on a `NSLog()`:

```
2012-05-18 21:59:52.176 ScrollApp[21443:f803] value for key is(
    "Image 4"
)
```

which is exactly the value I set on the plist.

But if I assign this values to the text of the label the compiler complain with `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

I know I will have to retrieve the returning value of the array as a string and pass it to the label.

The question is **how?**

This is the code:

```
NSArray *imgList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *imgName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[imgList objectAtIndex:3], nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [imgName valueForKey:@"Details"]);

NSString *currentPic = [imgName valueForKey:@"Details"];

subPanel.small_panel_Detail_Lbl.text =  currentPic;
```

Comment: Adding your code will help folks help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

valueForKey when sent to an array returns an array of all the values with that key in the array -- it may only be one value, but it will be in an array.  If you log [currentPic class], I'm guessing that it will be an array, so you need to send objectAtIndex to it to get a single string

Comment: Thanks....Your recommendation works Perfectly....i created another array that contained the values of [imgName valueForKey:@"Details"] and them create a string with the values of the new array